# Numbering rows based on multiple fields changes (incluging an "invisible" one) in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands, dense-rank

I had a look at the previous topics, but I cannot achieve what I want.

I have a table like this :

```
id   status     update_date
---  ---        ---
A    PENDING    2020-11-01
A    PENDING    2020-11-02
A    CONFIRMED  2020-11-03
A    CONFIRMED  2020-11-04
A    CONFIRMED  2020-11-05
A    PENDING    2020-11-06
A    PAID       2020-11-07
B    CONFIRMED  2020-11-02
etc.
```

and I want to have this :

```
id   status     rank
---  ---        ---
A    PENDING    1
A    CONFIRMED  2
A    PENDING    3
A    PAID       4
B    CONFIRMED  1
etc.
```

meaning taking into account the update_date (and of course the status change) to sort and number the rows, but NOT having the order date in the final result

PS: as you can see, I can go back and forth from one status to the other ( PENDING -> CONFIRMED -> PENDING -> etc.) multiple times

Thanks lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can address this as a gaps-and-island problem. The difference between row numbers gives you the group each record belongs to, that you can then use to aggregate:

```
select id, status, 
    row_number() over(partition by id order by min(update_date)) as rn
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by update_date) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by id, status order by update_date) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by id, status, rn1 - rn2
order by id, min(update_date)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1deab117b11e5986663074d1e93176d9)**:

```
id | status    | rn
:- | :-------- | -:
A  | PENDING   |  1
A  | CONFIRMED |  2
A  | PENDING   |  3
A  | PAID      |  4
B  | CONFIRMED |  1
```

Comment: thanks for this solution but postgresql greys the parts starting with row_number() and returns an "syntax error at or near "rn1""

Comment: @jeremoquai: there was a missing comma in the `group by` clause: fixed.

Comment: @jeremoquai: note that this is more efficient than the answer you accepted, because there is just one level of subquery (against two in the accepted solution).

Answer (score 1):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6c875a843999d9eabd0c1adbbbfa5ed2)

```
SELECT
    id, 
    status,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id)                                      -- 3
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        lead(status) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY update_date) AS next     -- 1
    FROM
        mytable
) s
WHERE status != next OR next is null                                         -- 2
```

1. [`lead()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) copies the next `status` value to the current record
2. Remove all records, where the current and the next `status` equal (no change of status)
3. add a row count with `row_number()` window function

Comment: thanks lot ! i wouldn't have found it myself